# React Native Scroll View - Can't scroll when selecting space in between Views

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a ScrollView with rows of circles inside of it. The ScrollView only scrolls when I select the circles, but doesn't scroll when I select the space in between the circles.

I'm trying to make a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/Skbiu_PEQ) but the website appears to be having issues. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was some strange interplay with a ScrollView inside of a [React Native Paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper) card.

I didn't quite get to the bottom of it but I solved the problem by removing my dependency on React Native Paper and making my own card.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a `FlatList` would be more adequate to your purpose:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: I could try it, but I don't see anything in the docs that indicates that it would fix my problem:

"This is where FlatList comes into play. FlatList renders items lazily, just when they are about to appear, and removes items that scroll way off screen to save memory and processing time.

FlatList is also handy if you want to render separators between your items, multiple columns, infinite scroll loading, or any number of other features it supports out of the box."